# should I turn off Smarty debug option?

Tags: html, codeigniter, validation, debugging, smarty

I use Codeigniter and Smarty template engine.

I did a form validation using Codeigniter's form validation library. So if user inputs some data I need to have a method to verify it.

If form passes validation no errors should be displayed in the view.

If form doesn't pass validation the I use this line of code: `$this->data['error_message'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();`

To store which errors occured.

So, in my template I did this:

```
<div id="cl-wrapper" class="login-container">

  <div class="middle-login">
    {if $error_message != ""}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">            
        {foreach from=$error_message item=curr_id}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle sign"></i><strong>Error!</strong> {$curr_id}<br/>
        {/foreach}
    </div>
    {/if}

    <div class="block-flat">
        //some code
    </div> 
  </div>    
</div>
```

The thing is that if form validates OK, a smarty template error is thrown:

Message: Undefined index: error_message

Filename: sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(151) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 65

I would like to know why, because I'm previosly asking if $error_message has something inside...

This didn't happened to me before...in another project.

Thanks in advance.

J.

**EDIT 13/05/2014**

I found a post [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-smarty-general/033mxybep0/error-php-notice-undefined-index) with same question. It says debugging should be off. I checked on Smarty.class.php and variable $debugging = false. So now I'm really lost...

Comment: Debugging is other option. If you set it to true, Smarty opens new window with some debug data but it doesn't affect displaying warnings

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Smarty doesn't know what $error_message is so the problem is not foreach loop but this comparison `{if $error_message != ""}` Remove foreach loop and check again.

You should check the place where you make assignment in PHP.

It should be something like this (I don't know codeigniter):

```
$smarty->assign('error_message', $this->data['error_message']);
```

Maybe the problem is that you should in Smarty use not $error_message but for example $data.error_message?

If you want to turn off Smarty errors, you should use muteExpectedErrors() function as described here - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.mute.expected.errors.tpl - it's from 3.1.2 version. Before you should use error_reporting - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.error.reporting.tpl to set desired level to Smarty object

Comment: Smarty should not return an error if a variable (like $error_message) doesn't have a value. I just want to know how to turn off this kind of control that smarty does when debugging

Comment: You should use muteExpectedErrors - added info to answer

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller if there is $data['error_message'].

Also you could do this if state with only ! or just check value.

```
{if $error_message}{/if}
```

Comment: yes, from my controller I'm sending $this->data['error_message'] but when I'm not.. then smarty shouldn't throw an error either (and that is what I want to fix).